# How to join multiple WHERE clauses together in SqlKata?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlkata

I am using [SqlKata](https://sqlkata.com/docs) to creating dynamic SQL queries. I have a list of conditions, stored in my database, which are generated according to my business rules. this is my code sample:

```
var list = new List<Query>();
foreach(var rule in rules){
    var q = new Query()
       .Where(x=> x.Where("Price", "<", rule.Price).OrWhere("GoodsType", "=", rule.Type));
    list.Add(q);
}
```

Now I want to join this list item together but none of **Where()** extensions overload accepts `Query` type parameters. Is there a way to join the where clauses together?

this is A VERY LITTLE PART OF expected query which I need to generate.

```
select * from ship_schedule where Path = @path and scheduleDate= @Date
AND (FD.IssueType ='O' OR fd.Path!='ILMTOP' OR  (fd.Path='ILMTOP' AND F.carrier !='MAL'))
AND (FD.IssueType ='O' OR fd.Path!='TOPILM' OR  (fd.Path='ILMTOP' AND F.carrier !='MAL'))
```

I need to create the second line of the query to the end.

Comment: Could you write the expected SQL ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Where` method is additive and calling it multiple times will add multiple conditions to the query, so you don't need to build the list of conditions by yourself.

```
var query = new Query("ship_schedule").Where("Path", path);

foreach(var rule in rules) {
  // loop over rules and append them to the query

  if(col == null) {

    query.WhereNull(col);

  } else {

    query.Where(q => 
      q.Where("Price", "<", rule.Price)
        .OrWhere("GoodsType", "=", rule.Type)
    )

  }
}
```

### Other ways

using the `When` method

```
query.When(condition, q => q.Where(...));
```

using the `WhereIf` method

```
query.WhereIf(condition, "Id", "=", 10);
```

Comment: I have some type of rules and I want to create the bunch of helper methods those create me where clause parts and then join them together.

Comment: and also Is some cases properties of my rules are empty or null and must be ignored. this means I must create this Where parts independently and join them in the final state.

Comment: I need a way to create bracket enclosed condition dynamically

Comment: why you can't do this inside the loop ?

Comment: loop is not my problem ... if and conditions break the fluent method.

Comment: I find a better way with WhereIf which enable me to check my rule data.